# Move input with focus out from under fixed header or fixed footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to set padding or margin, or call javascript to move the input element, with focus, out from under a fixed navbar and into view?

I am using bootstrap 3.1 and have created a bootply to show what I am struggling with.

The issue is when the user uses the "Tab" key to step through the input elements and an input element falls behind either the fixed top navbar or the fixed bottom navbar.

Having it become hidden under the top navbar is not as bad as the bottom navbar since control flow starts from the top. It is a problem with control flow if the user tabs back up the form.

Here is the URL for the bootply: http://bootply.com/110608#

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery animate to scroll the body as each input is focused..

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ele.offset().top - 80 /* 80 is height of navbar + input label */
    }, 800);
});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/110643

Comment: This looks neat, but I would imagine it will always scroll the element, right? Even if it is already in view...

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same issue, but I didn't want the animation for every input, here is an alternative based on Skelly's answer:

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    if (element.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < 80)
    {
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top - 80 /* 80 is height of navbar + input label */
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 This solution worked for a fixed header, but it did not work for a footer.  I posted an answer with a similar approach but for overlapping fixed footers.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with my footer overlapping my form elements and I didn't want a scroll action unless the element was covered by the footer. Here is how I did the bottom-up (footer) approach.

```
$('input, button, a').focus(function () {
    var footerHeight = 200; //footerHeight = footer height + element height + buffer
    var element = $(this);
    if (element.offset().top - ($(window).scrollTop()) > ($(window).height() - footerHeight)) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top - ($(window).height() - footerHeight)
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just CSS if your nav bars have fixed heights.

- Make sure html & body have height & max-height set to 100%.
- Remove `position: fixed` from your nav bar.
- Put the content in its own `<div>` adjacent to the nav bars, and give it a max-height of 100% minus the total height of the nav bars using the `calc` function.
- Also give `overflow-y: scroll` to this content div.

With this layout, the elements aren't overlapping at all so the focus problem goes away.

Example here: https://codepen.io/doodleygroover/pen/wvweKXv

This solution needs a bit of tweaking for nav bars with responsive heights. In this case, you'd need to add a bit of JS that listens for window resizing and updates the `max-height` property of the content `div`.